# How can I create my alternative database using List in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, treeview

I wanted to create a temporary database to test my application before I connect to our database. I wanted to populate those data from my alternative database in Treeview and Datagridview. My treeview would look like this:

Administrator

- Group

  - Users

    - Demo
    - Live
- Manager

Everytime I click a node, corresponding data will appear to my Datagridview. Like when I click "Group", data under it like "Users", etc will appear with their corresponding accounts like "Demo" and "Live". And when I click "Demo", its corresponding accounts also will appear. How can I do my alternative database with List in c#? Thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: Does it have to be a list, could you not just use `Datatable` ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class like this

```
public class TreeItem
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public List<TreeItem> Children {set;get;}
}
```

Now you can create a tree like this

```
var tree=new TreeItem();
tree.ID=1;
tree.Name="Group";

tree.Childrens=new List<TreeItem>();
var childUser=new TreeItem { ID=2, Name="User"};
tree.Childrens.Add(childUser);

childUser.Childrens=new List<TreeItem>();
var childDemo=new TreeItem { ID=3, Name="Demo"};
childUser.Childrens.Add(childDemo);

var childLive=new TreeItem { ID=4, Name="Live"};
childUser.Childrens.Add(childLive);
```

This is just hardcoding everything ! What you should ideally do is have this hierarchical data in an XML and then load your XML to this classes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for a pattern here.

[Composite Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx) seems to be the best match!

Sample code (not compiled):

```
public interface IComponent{
    string Name{get;}
    IEnumerable<IComponent> Childrens{get;}
}
public class Group : IComponent{
    private List<User> _users;
    ---
    IEnumerable<IComponent> Childerns{ get{ return _users;}}
}
public class User : IComponent {
    private List<Demo> _demos;
    private List<Live> _lives;

    IEnumerable<IComponent> Childresn { get { return _demos.Cast<IComponent>().Union(_lives.Cast<IComponent>()); }}
}
public class Demo : IComponent{..}
public class Live : IComponent {..}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the manual solution described by [@Shyju](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13907753/13198) is good for small number of items.

A better option will be to use a library like [AutoPoco](http://autopoco.codeplex.com/). A very good intro about its use was described by Scott Hanselmann sometime ago in [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode58GeneratingDatabaseTestDataWithAutoPocoAndEntityFrameworkCodeFirst.aspx).

Following example is slightly modified version (sans `Impose` constraint) of code lifted from Scott's blog post:

```
public void MakeTestData()
{
    IGenerationSessionFactory factory = AutoPocoContainer.Configure(x =>
    {
        x.Conventions(c => { c.UseDefaultConventions(); });
        x.AddFromAssemblyContainingType<SimpleUser>();
    });

    IGenerationSession session = factory.CreateSession();

    IList<SimpleUser> users = session.List<SimpleUser>(1000).Get();


}
```

The `IList<SimpleUser> users` now contains 1000 `SimpleUser` objects.